# L298 distorts signal

Tags: pwm, stm32, cmos, ttl, l298

I connected STM32 F334R8 microcontroller to L298 H-bridge. I made some measurements. The problem is output signal on L298 has quite slow slopes and is not as sharp as input signal. I do not understand why the distortion occurs. As you can see the frequency is very low - only 10 Hz.

- Pink color = L298 output signal,
- Yellow color = L298's Enable pin (STM32's PWM output),
- Green color = L298's Input 1 (STM32's output),
- Blue color = L298's Input 2 (STM32's output),

Input 1 and Input 2 determine direction of output current.

[image: Oscilloscope measurements low freq]

Also when we increase the frequency of PWM to 25 kHz and change duty cycle dynamically to achieve stepped sinusoidal signal, then output not always follows the input:
[image: Oscilloscope measurements high freq]

Not sure are the distortions showed on [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czKeK.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1RGG.png) related.

Note 1: Oscilloscope waveform acquire is in Hi-Res to average signals.

Note 2: On PWM output (yellow) I am generating abs(stepped_sin(x)). Then to make stepped_sin() on the L298 output I am changing Input 1 and Input 2 (just inverting current direction).

I'm just curious what's the reason of such strange behavior.

L298 logic supply voltage is 5 V, power supply voltage is 8 V. Output load is 4Ω power resistor.

I have already checked L298 datasheet and typical PWM switching frequency is 25 kHz. Also input's logical high starts with 2.3 V. My microcontroller uses 3.3 V logic so it should be sufficient, isn't it?

Comment: Why do you fiddle with the enable pin during normal operation?

Comment: Because enable pin usually used for PWM, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have low ESR Cap across IC?   Since the ESR of each driver is close to 1 Ohm and the total drop is >3V @ 1A and >4V @ 2A the L298 is not a good candidate at low supply voltage<12V A better candidate is a MOSFET bridge

Comment: The L298 is a horrible, antiquated, lossy part. If you want firm drive use an FET solution.

Comment: Why do you have channel 4 (pink) on 50 ohms mode?

Comment: Just using differential probe. Three other are single ended.